# Using Volley, How to get Cookie value(s) from response coming from server?

Tags: android, android-volley

i am using Volley to make connection, Volley manages session management automatically. I want to get Cookie value(s) from Response, and set Cookie Value to subsequent Request.

How to get Cookie value from Response, and set into Request ?

Comment: @Slartibartfast i already followed-up that solution but it is not what i am asking.

Comment: Sandeep, did you ever work this out, I have the same question.